# How to alternate between two different lists in Razor syntax?

Tags: c#, html, razor

I'm drawing a blank on this. I have two foreach loops that are creating div's and I'm trying to get 1 or two items from the 2nd foreach to display every 2 items from the first foreach.... here's the code..

```
@foreach (var stream in Model.LiveStreams)
{
    <div id="divLiveStream" class="well-livestream well-sm">
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="ui-icon-image">
                  <img src="~/Images/placeholder.jpg" width="100%" />
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-10">
              <div class="text-left row">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                         @stream.UserName
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                         @stream.Status
                   </div>
              </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
}
@foreach (var post in Model.LivePosts)
{
   <div id="divLivePost" class="well-liveposts well-sm">
     <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="ui-icon-image">
                  <img src="~/Images/placeholder.jpg" width="100%" />
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-10">
              <div class="text-left row">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                       @post.AspNetUser.UserName
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                       @post.PostDescription
                  </div>
              </div>
         </div>
     </div>
  </div>
}
```

So for further clarification, I'm trying to display 2 divLiveStreams, then display 2 divLivePost, and continue on with that pattern. I'm new to MVC so I'm not sure how to go about this and I'm drawing all kinds of blanks on this Friday.. Thanks in advance!

Edit: Here is my ViewModel.

```
public class LiveStreamViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<LiveStream> LiveStreams { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<tPost> LivePosts { get; set; }
}
```

Edit: Probably a dumb question, but I use my controller to return the model. Before I had my controller like below, how am I suppose to call the new ViewModel that you created in the controller?
Here is my Controller.

```
public ActionResult LiveStream()
{
    Service service = new Service();
    LiveStreamViewModel model = new LiveStreamViewModel
    {
        LiveStreams = service.GetLiveStream(),
        LivePosts = service.GetLivePosts()
    };
    if (TempData["Message"] != null) ViewBag.Message = TempData["Message"]; ViewBag.Header = "Success!";

     return View(model);
    }
}
```

And my data service.

```
public IEnumerable<LiveStream> GetLiveStream()
{
    using (dboMyJeepTraderEntities context = new dboMyJeepTraderEntities())
    {
        return (from s in context.tStatusUpdates select new LiveStream 
        { 
            Status = s.Status,
            UserName = s.AspNetUser.UserName
        }).ToList();
    }

}

public IEnumerable<tPost> GetLivePosts()
{
    return (from p in _context.tPosts select p).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need one viewmodel, with the alternation happening with the ***hydration*** of the viewmodel.

```
public abstract class AbstractThing
{
    public abstract string TheUserName { get; }
    public abstract string TheDescription { get; }
}

public class LivePost : AbstractThing
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string PostDescription { get; set; }

    public override string TheUserName
    {
        get { return this.UserName; }
    }

    public override string TheDescription
    {
        get { return this.PostDescription; }
    }
}


public class LiveStream : AbstractThing
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }

    public override string TheUserName
    {
        get { return this.UserName; }
    }

    public override string TheDescription
    {
        get { return this.Status; }
    }

}


public class AlternatingThingsViewModel
{

    public ICollection<AbstractThing> AbstractThings { get; private set; }

    public AlternatingThingsViewModel(ICollection<LivePost> lps, ICollection<LiveStream> lss)
    {

        this.AbstractThings = new List<AbstractThing>();

        /* this is not correct...here is where you would "two by two" add items to the this.AbstractThings in the order you want.  the key is to have one collection exposed by the viewmodel */

        if (null != lps)
        {
            foreach (AbstractThing at in lps)
            {
                this.AbstractThings.Add(at);
            }
        }

        if (null != lss)
        {
            foreach (AbstractThing at in lss)
            {
                this.AbstractThings.Add(at);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Now you loop on the single collection

```
@foreach (var post in Model.AbstractThings)
{
   <div id="divLivePost" class="well-liveposts well-sm">
     <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="ui-icon-image">
                  <img src="~/Images/placeholder.jpg" width="100%" />
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-10">
              <div class="text-left row">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                       @post.TheUserName
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                       @post.TheDescription
                  </div>
              </div>
         </div>
     </div>
  </div>
}
```

Below is a "one then other one" implementation...as long as the LivePost count is greater than the LiveStream.  And no error checking.  But gives you an idea.

```
public class AlternatingThingsViewModel
{

    public ICollection<AbstractThing> AbstractThings { get; private set; }

    public AlternatingThingsViewModel(ICollection<LivePost> lps, ICollection<LiveStream> lss)
    {
        this.AbstractThings = new List<AbstractThing>();
        /* this is a "one by one" with no error checking if the counts are different */

        IEnumerator<AbstractThing> livePostEnum = null == lps ? null : lps.GetEnumerator();
        IEnumerator<AbstractThing> liveStreamEnum = null == lss ? null : lss.GetEnumerator();

        if (null != liveStreamEnum)
        {
            liveStreamEnum.MoveNext();
        }

        if (null != livePostEnum)
        {
            while (livePostEnum.MoveNext() == true)
            {
                AbstractThing lpCurrent = livePostEnum.Current;
                AbstractThing lsCurrent = null == liveStreamEnum ? null : liveStreamEnum.Current;
                if (null != liveStreamEnum)
                {
                    liveStreamEnum.MoveNext();
                }

                this.AbstractThings.Add(lpCurrent);
                if (null != lsCurrent)
                {
                    this.AbstractThings.Add(lsCurrent);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and some calling code.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        try
        {

            ICollection<LivePost> lps = new List<LivePost>();
            lps.Add(new LivePost() { UserName = "LivePostUserName1", PostDescription = "LivePostDescription1" });
            lps.Add(new LivePost() { UserName = "LivePostUserName2", PostDescription = "LivePostDescription2" });
            lps.Add(new LivePost() { UserName = "LivePostUserName3", PostDescription = "LivePostDescription3" });
            lps.Add(new LivePost() { UserName = "LivePostUserName4", PostDescription = "LivePostDescription4" });

            ICollection<LiveStream> lss = new List<LiveStream>();
            lss.Add(new LiveStream() { UserName = "LiveStreamUserName1", Status = "LiveStreamStatus1" });
            lss.Add(new LiveStream() { UserName = "LiveStreamUserName2", Status = "LiveStreamStatus2" });
            //lss.Add(new LiveStream() { UserName = "LiveStreamUserName3", Status = "LiveStreamStatus3" });


            AlternatingThingsViewModel atmv = new AlternatingThingsViewModel(lps, lss);

            int modCheckCount = 0;
            foreach (AbstractThing at in atmv.AbstractThings)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", at.TheUserName, at.TheDescription);

                if (++modCheckCount % 2 == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                }
            }
```

Comment: waaa? I do have a ViewModel.. I'll update to show that as well.. can you elaborate on this?

Comment: Cool, I appreciate it. I've edited my question to add the current ViewModel I'm using.

Comment: The ViewModel needs to be "perfect" before binding.  That's the point of the VIewModel..."massage the data" so it can be displayed.  You don't want to do the "jumping".   You need to encapsualte the "two by two" logic in the AlternatingThingsViewModel and handle things like "what happens when I have 50 LivePosts and 3 LiveStreams"

Comment: ahhh, sweet. I'll give this a shot tonight! Thanks for the help!

Comment: I've updated my question a bit, can you clarify a bit more for me since I'm new the MVC?

Comment: public ActionResult Something()
{
   /* get your 2  collections, coll1 and coll2 */

  AlternatingThingsViewModel vm = new AlternatingThingsViewModel(coll1, coll2); /* update the logic inside of AlternatingThingsViewModel to handle 2 by 2 hyrdation */

     return View(model);
    }
}

Comment: I had to move the AbstractThings, LivePosts, LiveStreams to my Model in my Database project, then I was able to pass the collections properly. Thanks for the help! This solution is nice.

Answer (score 0):

Well, so - yeah - doing it in the `Controller` obviously makes sense. But, then again, Razor is just (mostly) C# so whatever you can do in one you can do in the other:

```
@{
    var streamIndex = 0;
    var postIndex = 0;
}
@while (streamIndex < Model.LiveStreams.Count() || postIndex < Model.LivePosts.Count()) {
    @foreach (var stream in Model.LiveStreams.Skip(streamIndex).Take(2)) {
       // html code
       streamIndex++;
    }
    @foreach (var post in Model.LivePosts.Skip(postIndex).Take(2)) {
       // html code
       postIndex++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, this sorta works, but from what I've tested it only display's 2 of each so if there is more status' or more posts, those don't get displayed.

Comment: Please don't write logic in the View.  Please don't write logic in the View.   And please don't use this answer with logic in the View.  "so whatever you can do in one you can do in the other"  I can write DataReaders in button click events, but that is a poor way to do it.   The "2 by 2" code here is good, but it should not be in the View.

Comment: @granadaCoder - why not? this is view logic, after all - it's simply about how to layout the view. With the combined collection in the Model, you'll likely end up with an @(post is LivePost ? "post" : "stream") at some point - does that count as logic? Why not? It's an if statement. FWIW - I'd be much more concerned with forcing an inheritance relationship that doesn't logically exist than some while loops in a view....

Comment: @Humpy - yeah, there were some off-by-one (or more) bugs in there; fixed.

Comment: The "view" is the hardest thing to UnitTest, thus the most you can remove from the View, the better.  Controllers and ViewModels are easier to UnitTest.  That would be my reasons.  I'm not saying no logic ever in the View..but minimizing it is the best practice IMHO.

Comment: @granadaCoder - which is pretty much my point; this isn't something I see as needing a unit test any more than I'd test that if I sent 10 items in my ViewModel that 10 table rows come out. This looks like view logic to me - not business logic. But yeah - you can put the code wherever it feels better for you. :)